How to display viva engage communities a user belongs to in SharePoint Online
I'm looking for a way to display viva engage communities a user belongs to in SharePoint Online.
I know I can see that via MS Teams.But the OTTB viva engage web parts in SharePoint doesn't provide the options to display this.
What are my alternatives to use the yammer graph rest api and build a custom web part?
Anyone done this before?

There is no web part available for this exact requirement. Here is a SPFx web part showing how to use Yammer API in SPFx: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-yammer-api
